# Eclipse starting tomcat with compile errors

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

This is a simple issue: the default behavior of eclipse is to start tomcat even if the project has compilation errors.

How I turn this "feature" off, so that eclipse complains about compilation errors and prevents Tomcat from starting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't turn this feature off in Eclipse.

There are several things to note here:

Tomcat is an external process, and you publish to it. So, what you really want is that you don't publish to it when you have an error. You could have an error in a JSP, in an XML file, anything.

Tomcat may already be running. What would you do in this case? Restart the server? Remove the class file from the tomcat config? You can't always do this. For instance under windows, if the file is open, then the .class file can't be deleted.

Also, when Eclipse compiles a java file, and it finds a compilation error, it still creates the class file, but with something like[*]:

```
public void foo() {
    throw new Error("Unresolved compilation problem: \n\tFOOBAR cannot be resolved\n");
}
```

which means that the class file is technically valid.

When you're running external processes, you are no longer under the complete control of Eclipse, so the same rules don't apply. You can always ask for the new feature though.

[*] You can check this using [jad](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad) or similar.

Comment: This was useful. Unfortunately, it just drove down my respect for eclipse even further. It automagically changes my code, without telling me, so that it can satisfy compile errors? Effectively what I want is eclipse not to publish automatically my changes to tomcat, unless I tell it to. Once this behavior can be enforced, then it can do checks and only once I have no compile issues or any jsp issues or any other validation issues (xml, etc) it can publish. I wonder why this was not the default behavior, I guess the designers thought it would be a great feature that would speed up development.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

[image: Prompt for launch]

Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Continue launch if project contains errors.  The default is "Prompt", so either you inadvertently changed it to "always", or Tomcat launches do not respect this setting.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no such setting in eclipse. There is an errors tab which will show you if the project has problems. That should catch compilation errors too.